# Переодеть майку

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, приставка

Майки **на**девают. Когда майку меняют, её тоже **на**девают. А теперь, внимание, вопрос: почему словосочетание "переодеть майку" верное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотря что имеется в виду. 
Если "переодеть" - сменить майку на другую, то словари такого варианта пока не разрешают. А почему вы решили, что сочетание "переодеть майку" верное?
Переодеть можно Майку. А майку - только перенадеть. Беда только в том, что слова "перенадеть" в русском нету. А если и есть, то не в нужном нам значении. Поэтому, боюсь, что "неправильный" вариант таки победит. Вы это имели в виду говоря "сочетание верное"?

Посмотрел. Оказывается, уже. Я отстал от жизни, хотя и предвидел такое развитие событий.
"Переодеть. Одеть в другую одежду. П. сына в новый костюм. П. рубашку" (БТС Кузнецова).
Последнее ("П. рубашку") - и даже без помет - означает, что словарь признает вариант "переодеть рубашку" нормативным. 
*Придется плюсануть за вопрос с неожиданным ответом.*
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Посыпаю голову пеплом. Оказавается "Справка" уже довольно давно отвечала на этот вопрос, почему-то с первого раза не нашел...
Остаётся только исправиться и порадоваться за тех, кто усомнился в ненормативности переодевания маек.

*Вопрос № 257978

Здравствуйте! Скажите пожалуйста, как правильно сказать : переодеть носки или перенадеть носки? Спасибо.

потолок*

*Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Слова перенадеть нет в русском языке. В значении 'сняв одно, надеть на себя другое' употребляется глагол переодеть: переодеть носки.*

При всей неавторитетности собственно "Справки" как таковой, у кого ещё спрашивать, я не знаю. Тем более, что запрет на такое переодевание явно нигде не прописан.

*Я сидел высоко, на самой верхушке дерева, на маленькой жалкой ветке и с опасностью для жизни переодевал носки. - Ха-ха, все-то ты врешь! - сказал Малыш. - Откуда у тебя на дереве взялись носки? - А ты вовсе не так глуп, как кажешься, - заметил Карлссон. - Так, по-твоему, у меня не было носков, чтоб их переодеть? Задрав штанины, он выставил свои толстые ножки-колбаски в полосатых носках. - А это что? - возмущенно спросил он. - Может, это не носки? Два носка, если зрение мне не изменяет. А разве я не сидел на ветке и не менял до одури носки, да так, что напялил левый на правую ногу, а правый на левую?*
("Карлсон вернулся")

**Внимание, ответ! Выражение "переодеть майку" верно потому, что глагола "перенадеть" в русском нет.**

Comment: В словарях, даже самых уважаемых,  тоже бывают ошибки. В школьном орфографическом словаре нашла "дистиЛированный" с одной Л. В словаре Ушакова - "сИмпровизировать". Примеры предложений типа "День, как год" идут с запятой... Нельзя "переодеть рубашку"! Никак нельзя.

Comment: Если по вашим примерам, то школьный это не словарь, а Ушаков издавался тогда, когда за ошибки расстреривали. Наверняка есть объяснение.
К тому же Кузнецов - толковый словарь, а ваши примеры - на орфографию.
Так что можно говорить максимум о личном снении автора, "опечаток" таких не бывает. Я попробую задать вопрос на Грамоте. Видимо, пришла пора мне туда вернуться.

Comment: Дадите ссылку на ответ.

Comment: Словарь Кузнецова не является нормативным. Поэтому "переодеть рубашку" - это всего лишь пример. Он отражает живое словоупотребление, только и всего.

Comment: @olsa, не это не смешно даже. В этом смысле ни один словарь не является нормативным.

Comment: Словарь Ушакова, БАС и МАС были нормативными :-))

Comment: Каждый в своей области. Да и то там политики больше было. 
Словарь Кузнецова тоже толковый, и по этой части уж никак не менее нормативен толковому же Ушакова. Другое дело, если противопоставлять словорям упраления, сочетаемости и проч. Но у меня таковых нет в зоне ближней досягаемости.

Comment: Ну вот! Я всегда поправляю "одеть нечто" на "надеть", но "переодень (майку, носки, рубашку и т.п.)" говорю не задумываясь. Что же теперь делать - бороться с собой, или уступить-таки удобству выражения?

Comment: @DocentI, здесь не паникуте, здесь ействительно есть с чем разбираться. Как я уже сказал, отсутствие нормативного (в строгом понимании) эквивалента - уже причина призадуматься.

Comment: @behemothus, спасибо, успокоили, Вы настоящий друг ;-))  
Видимо, язык заполняет как может эту смысловую нишу.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что со словом "майку" это словосочетание неверное. Можно майку, например, сменить или надеть другую. "Переодеть" можно кого-то, но не что-то.
А вот Майку переодеть - это пожалуйста! Если она не будет возражать, конечно...

Answer (score 0):

Словарь Ушакова и словарь Ожегова разрешают *переодеть платье*, словарь Кузнецова позволяет *переодеть рубашку*, а Словарь ошибок русского языка говорит: "Широко распространенное *переодеть платье* – грубая ошибка". Вот и разберись (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/211559/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)

*Переодевают рубашку* Фазиль Искандер и Юрий Трифонов (найдено в Нацкорпусе).
Похоже, надо с этим смириться.