# Глагол "переодеть"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сказал вчера: "Переодену куртку". И как-то стало не по себе, ведь "одеть куртку" нельзя (ну только если в режиме психических отклонений или в детских играх), и приставка ПЕРЕ вроде кардинально не меняет характеристики глагола. Тогда нужно говорить "перенадеть", но так тоже нельзя. Вот, думаю, с ОДЕТЬ/НАДЕТЬ вроде как ситуация выправляется (или мне так кажется), а с ПЕРЕОДЕТЬ получается та же ошибка... Смотрю в Большой толковый словарь на [Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C):

> **ПЕРЕОДЕТЬ,** -одену, -оденешь; переодетый; -дет, -а, -о; ***св.** кого-что.* Одеть в другую одежду. *П. сына в новый костюм. П. рубашку.*

"Переодеть рубашку"! Так что же – не ошибка? Или просто правила адаптируются к разговорному языку, и если большинство всё же будет говорить "одеть рубашку", то количество перерастёт в качество и мы увидим это в словарях?

Comment: Возможно, мы уже дожили до "одеть рубашку". Тут нужна статистика, причем разговорная.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9461/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%83

Comment: Если обратиться к словарям, то по Далю это неправильно (можно переодеть только "кого"), у Ушакова "п. что" трактуется как "разговорное", а Ожегов буквально повторяет ушаковскую статью, уже без пометки. Видимо, оттуда "Грамота" и почерпнула.

Comment: @Alex_ander  Спасибо за ссылку